# Option to disable autocorrect is gone in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'm trying to disable autocorrect in windows 11.

Problem is that the option isnt there to toggle it.

When I upgraded my computer from Windows 10 I noticed that the "normal installer" did not work for me so I had to create a bootable usb in order to make it work.

As you see here the option isnt there:

[image]

[image]

Feels like I have some other version of Windows 11 than most have :(

How can I fix this? It's driving me mental when writing a mail in swedish and it keeps autocorrecting things to english.

**Course of action:**

[image]

Added that key.

Next I restarted computer and it said it was updating something. (When shutting down).

Opened up a new mail and noticed that I still had same problem. ("i" gets turned into "I").

Then I noticed a bar poping up in windows mail were it said something about "propping" and "Office".

Clicked that one and a help info showed to right next to windows mail. Were there was a link to settings so I clicked that.

Clicked that and noticed that I only had "English" language pack. Can't remember exactly which but.. So somehow adding that thing in the registry removed Swedish language and regional settings, must have fallen back to some default thing.

(Can't remember if I restarted here or not).

Then things got abit weird. Out of nowhere there was some message about "Propping" something.

And this one showed up and I clicked update on the email+calendar app thing.

[image]

After it updated I restarted the computer (just in case or something).

(And as a "bonus" it said it updated Excel(-something) which is kinda weird since I don't have Office. I use LibreOffice.)

After that I checked the typing settings and it looked like this now:

[image]

**Problem solved!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just be very careful when you mess with the registry, and be sure to back up any important documents because any accidental changes to the wrong registry items can result in operating system failure.

It appears the settings you are looking for is missing in Windows 11 and will probably get fixed in a future update.

The below instructions are applicable to Windows 10, and there is a chance the folder tree structure you see inside regedit does not match inside Windows 11. **If it does not match, do not make any changes!** Just let me know in the comments and I will modify my answer to help further.

**Run regedit**

Press “Windows + R” to open the Run dialog, type “regedit”, and press “OK”.

[image]

Navigate to the Windows typing settings registry key and create a new DWORD (32-bit)

In the Registry Editor address bar, paste Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7. In the main pane, right-click any empty space and select “New > DWORD (32-bit) Value”. If prompted, name it “EnableAutocorrection”.

[image]

Turn Windows autocorrect on or off

Double click the DWORD to open the properties window, then modify the “Value data” to your choosing:

1 = **Enable** Windows autocorrect

0 = **Disable** Windows autocorrect

Removing the registry key will have your PC follow the system settings once more. Once you’re done modifying, click “OK”.

[image]

Original Information Source [Here](https://winbuzzer.com/2020/07/24/how-to-turn-windows-10-spell-check-and-windows-autocorrect-on-or-off-xcxwbt/)

Comment: A million thanks for helping me solve this issue! You're a rockstar!

Comment: Happy to help, many here have helped me and i do lurk this site looking for questions i can answer. Always good to give back :)